# How to echo meta title and meta tags using DOMDocument and DOMXPath

Tags: php, codeigniter, domdocument, domxpath

Using this function:

```
function get_tags($adres)
{
    $dom = new domDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    if (!$dom->loadHTML($adres)) {
        echo "Error";
    } else echo "Load ok";
    $html = new DOMXPath($dom);
   $html->query('//title');
}
```

I try to get and echo title and keywords, description, robots meta tags using XPath, but don't know how and how must look query for meta tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the title, I use :

```
$titles = $xpath->query('/html/head/title');
foreach ($titles as $title) {
    $return['title'][] = $title->nodeValue;
}
```

Because it's possible that the DOM has multiple `<title />` tags, though it is not recommended.

I then parse all the `<meta />` tags, as such :

```
$metas = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta');
foreach ($metas as $meta) {
    $name = strtolower($meta->getAttribute('name'));
    if ($name == 'title' && (!isset($return['title']) || $return['title'] == '')) // There is such a thing as <meta name="title" \>
        $return['title'][] = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if ($name == 'keywords')
        $return['metakw'][] = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if ($name == 'description')
        $return['metadesc'][] = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if ($name == 'robots')
        $return['robots'][] = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}
```

But I guess it would be possible to use :

```
$metas_title = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="title"]');
$metas_desc = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]');
$metas_kw = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="keywords"]');
$metas_robots = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="robots"]');
```

Comment: So using this $metas_title = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="title"]'); how print $meta_title value?

Comment: This will give you an array of meta tags, you have to iterate through it (using a simple `foreach`, for instance) and then use `$meta->getAttribute('content');`. But beware that  `<meta name="title" />` is very rare and often an error, the correct syntax is `<title />`.

Comment: i see something like this $return['title'][] first time, sorry but still don't know what to do with this :/

Comment: Well, `$return['title']` is an array containing every `<title />` and `<meta name="title" />` contents. Just loop through it using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php) and treat each iteration (for instance echo them)

Comment: $metas = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta');
var_dump($metas) return object(DOMNodeList)#17 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } so that mean no results found?